# How can I export types from @tanstack/react-table in a Rollup-built TypeScript library?

Tags: typescript, bundle, rollup

Rollup not exporting types for @tanstack/libray library

So, I'm trying to build, using rollup, a typescript library and in this library I create a wrapper over the @tanstack/react-table. When I import the build up libray in a project the types that were used are seen as any.  So I searched for the types in the lib folder, but I only find the custom types created by me without the types defined in react-table library. How can I config rollup to export types from react-table?